# Converting a LINQ query into a Dictionary<string, string[]>

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, dictionary

I've got a query that returns something of the following format:

```
{ "tesla", "model s" }
{ "tesla", "roadster" }
{ "honda", "civic" }
{ "honda", "accord" }
```

and I'd like to convert that to a dictionary of `<string, string[]>` like so:

```
{ "tesla" : ["model s", "roadster"],  "honda" : ["civic", "accord"] }
```

I've tried with this:

```
var result = query.Select(q => new { q.Manufacturer, q.Car}).Distinct().ToDictionary(q => q.Manufacturer.ToString(), q => q.Car.ToArray());
```

but so far I am not having any luck. I think what this is doing is actually trying to add individual items like `"tesla" : ["model s"]` and `"tesla" : ["roadster"]` and that's why it's failing ... any easy way to accomplish what I am trying to do in LINQ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to group each item by the key first, then construct the dictionary:

```
result = query.Select(q => new { q.Manufacturer, q.Car}).Distinct()
              .GroupBy(q => q.Manufacturer)
              .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                            g => g.Select(q => q.Car).ToArray());
```

Of course, an [`ILookup<string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx) much easier:

```
result = query.Select(q => new { q.Manufacturer, q.Car }).Distinct()
              .ToLookup(q => q.Manufacturer, q => q.Car);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `ToLookup` if you would like the results to be grouped into a dictionary-like object:

```
var result = query.Select(q => new { q.Manufacturer, q.Car})
                  .Distinct()
                  .ToLookup(q => q.Manufacturer.ToString(), q => q.Car);
```

Otherwise you will have to group the results first:

```
var result = query.Select(q => new { q.Manufacturer, q.Car })
                  .Distinct()
                  .GroupBy(q => q.Manufacturer)
                  .ToDictionary(gg => gg.Key,
                                gg => gg.Select(q => q.Car).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `GroupBy()`, followed by `ToDictionary()`.

Example:

```
var result = query.GroupBy(q => q.Manufacturer).ToDictionary(q => q.Key, q => q.Value.ToArray());
```

What `GroupBy()` does is group all the elements that have the same matching key selector. So when you tell it to `GroupBy(q => q.Manufacturer)`, all the elements that have the same Manufacturer will be grouped together as `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx):

```
var table = pairs.ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

foreach(var i in table["tesla"])
   Console.WriteLine(i);
```